Проблема с запуском исполняемых файлов с флешки
Есть флешка, отформатированная в ext2. Попробовал запустить с неё исполняемый файл: не запускается, выводит:

zsh: permission denied: <Имя файла>

от рута тоже самое
Флешка монтирована с флагами: auto defaults,rw,nofail в fstab.
Флаг x на файле присутсвует.
В ~/ нормально запускается.
Как сделать так, чтобы можно было запускать с флешки?

Флаг x-то на файле стоит?

@Pavel Mayorov Канешн

А вы уверены, что именно «не запускается», а не «запускается и падает с ошибкой»? Что если создать #!/bin/sh скрипт с простым echo "я работаю"?

А вообще посмотрите фактически применившиеся флаги монтирования командой mount или в /proc/mounts, вдруг там всё-таки откуда-то noexec затесался

посмотрите file <Имя файла>, ldd <Имя файла>  и  uname -a чтоб проверить мою догадку

@andreymal это не скрипт. и noexec всётаки там затесался /dev/sda /media/usb ext2 rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,errors=continue,user_xattr,acl 0 0. Теперь вопрос а как его убрать

@eri ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1, BuildID[sha1]=67b22eb06d2b6e8f12046b790bed7a01d83d5838, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, with debug_info, not stripped not a dynamic executable Linux orangepizero3 6.1.31-sun50iw9 #1.0.2 SMP Thu Sep 28 12:14:12 CST 2023 aarch64 GNU/Linux

«это не скрипт» — ну вот я к тому, что сперва добейтесь, чтобы хотя бы простой скрипт запускался, а уже потом можно будет с конкретным исполняемым файлом разбираться

«а как его убрать» — скорее всего поможет явное прописывание флага exec в fstab, хотя это не решит вопрос, откуда noexec вообще взялся

Удивительно, но если добавить в /etc/fstab users,exec 0 0 в конец строки в которой указывается монтировать проблемный диск, то после перезагрузки всё OK
Как то так:
/dev/sda /media/usb auto defaults,rw,nofail,users,exec 0 0

users? Вы в вопросе никакой users не упоминали, а именно он и добавляет noexec

@andreymal а его и не было :)

Скорее всего файл не той архитектуры. Например arm64 пытаетесь запустить на armhf ядре.

А в такой ситуации разве не должно выводиться банальное cannot execute binary file: Exec format error?

Это когда вообще не совместимую пытатесь запустить.  я встречал именно permission denied, когда на системе не стоял multi-arch.

с этим всё ок, использовался arm64 компилятор с arm64 линуксом
